# How to do a timeout in WWW::Scripter

Tags: perl, timeout, cgi

I'm parsing a web site using `WWW::Scripter` for Perl.

Is there a way to include a timeout, e.g. 10 seconds. `eval` generally works for timeouts quite well, but in this case, it does not.

[`WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript`](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-Plugin-JavaScript-0.009/lib/WWW/Scripter/Plugin/JavaScript.pm)

Answer (score 2):

[WWW::Scripter](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Scripter) is a subclass of [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize). And WWW::Mechanize is, in turn, a subclass of [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent). So you can call all of LWP::UserAgent's methods on your WWW::Scripter object. And that includes `timeout()`.

```
my $scripter = WWW::Scripter->new;
$scripter->timeout(10);
$scripter->get($some_url);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. I am using $w->use_plugin('JavaScript');    also...there is no timeout at all :( Any other ideas?